# Are pointer to slices good "relationships" in Go with GAE Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

according to [Ancestor Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Ancestor_filters) from the App Engine docs, I can do something like this:

```
type Team struct {
    Name string
}

type Player struct {
    Name string
}

// Save data first just for the test case
teamA := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Team", nil)
teamA, _ = datastore.Put(c, teamA, Team{"Team A"})
playerA := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Player", teamA)
playerA, _ = datastore.Put(c, playerA, Player{"Player A"})
playerB := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Player", teamA)
playerB , _ = datastore.Put(c, playerB, Player{"Player B"})

// query data
q := datastore.NewQuery("Team").Filter("Name=", "Team A").Limit(1).KeysOnly()
teams, _ := q.GetAll(c, nil)
q = datastore.NewQuery("Player").Ancestor(teams[0])
var players []Player
q.GetAll(c, &players)
```

However... What if I want to have Team to include a pointer to an slice of player, so I would save it as nil, and when I query it, I would assign it, sort of like this:

```
type Team struct {
    Name string
    Players *[]Player `datastore:-`
}

type Player {
    Name string
}

// Save data first just for the test case
teamA := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Team", nil)
teamA, _ = datastore.Put(c, teamA, Team{"Team A", nil})

/* Saving player data goes here */

// query data
q := datastore.NewQuery("Team").Filter("Name=", "Team A").Limit(1)
var teams []Team
teamKeys, _ := q.GetAll(c, teams)
q = datastore.NewQuery("Player").Ancestor(teamKeys[0])
q.GetAll(c, teams[0].Players)
```

Would that be a good approach for simulating relationships?
For my app, a tree structure would be the ring that perfectly fits my finger.
Or maybe... do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a pointer is a valid type for datastore!
From here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference

> An entity's contents are a mapping from case-sensitive field names to
>   values. Valid value types are:

```
- signed integers (int, int8, int16, int32 and int64),
- bool,
- string,
- float32 and float64,
- any type whose underlying type is one of the above predeclared types,
- *Key,
- time.Time,
- appengine.BlobKey,
- []byte (up to 1 megabyte in length),
- structs whose fields are all valid value types,
- slices of any of the above.
```

*Or maybe... do you have another suggestion?*
A slice to Player may work (not tested)
Or maybe you should search for ["The PropertyLoadSaver Interface"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface) in the same URL. It just something like you choose what and how you insert thing to datasotre rather than let it auto.

Comment: I actually ended up using the PropertyLoadSaver, I do have an empty slice `[]Player` with `\`datastore:-\``, and another slice of the `*Key`s. Then I implemented the PropertyLoadSaver to load the `Player`s into the slice, from the `*Key`s.

Comment: Also, about the pointer... I meant that... I wanted to be able to have a nil value, and not actually save it, I forgot putting the `\`datastore:-\`` thingy (I have updated the code)

Comment: I think you may still want []*Palyer with the PropertyLoadSaver

Comment: Ah yeah oops, I tried to imply that I was not using a pointer to a slice, but just a slice, so.. yeah